# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException during Long division (Column Division)

Tags: java, arraylist

I make a program that simulates long division(column division). Everything is working correctly as i expected, except examples with dividend digits that is similar to divider or very close to divider (only in case if dividend has one digit more than divider). In this case i got java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException. Could somebody advice me where is my mistake?
My code:

```
public class Division {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int dividend = scan.nextInt();
    int divider = scan.nextInt();
    divisionEngine(dividend, divider);
    scan.close();
}

public static List<Integer> getDigits(int dividend) {
    List<Integer> digitArray = new ArrayList<>();

    while (dividend > 0) {
        digitArray.add(dividend % 10);
        dividend = dividend / 10;
    }
    Collections.reverse(digitArray);
    return digitArray;
}

public static int divisionEngine(int dividend, int divider) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int dividerLength = String.valueOf(divider).length();
    int result = 0;
    int substraction = 0;
    int variable = Integer.parseInt(getDigits(dividend).subList(0, dividerLength).toString().replace("[", "")
            .replace("]", "").replace(", ", ""));
    int initVariable = variable;

    while (dividerLength != getDigits(dividend).size()) {
        result = Math.abs(variable / divider);
        builder.append(result);
        substraction = Math.abs(result * divider);
        variable = Integer.parseInt(variable - substraction + "".concat(getDigits(dividend).get(dividerLength++)
                .toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(", ", "")));

        if (variable < divider && variable < initVariable) {
            variable = Integer.parseInt(variable + "".concat(getDigits(dividend).get(dividerLength++)
                    .toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(", ", "")));
            builder.append(0);
        }

        if (substraction != 0 && variable != initVariable) {
            System.out.println(substraction + "\n" + variable);
        }
    }

    if (dividerLength == getDigits(dividend).size()) {
        result = Math.abs(variable / divider);
        substraction = Math.abs(result * divider);
        variable -= Math.abs(substraction);
        builder.append(result);
        result = Integer.parseInt(builder.toString());

        if (substraction != 0) {
            System.out.println(substraction + "\n" + variable);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("= " + result);

    return result;
}
```

}

Finally should be something like this:

[image: Long Division]

At this stage in my class i have only mathematics solving without drawing a String formatting to receive same picture, but before i continue with String formatting i have to solve this annoying problem.

Also here is my print outs from the console:
Working examples:
[image: like this is OK]
[image: and like this is OK]
[image: and like this is also ok]
[image]

Not working example:
[image: like this i have an exception]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after two days i solved my problem. Answer from @dognose was not accepted because it's not solved my problem, but it was very close and i appreciate to much for @dognose, because it's help me to understand where is my mistake.

Here is my final code at this stage, next step for me is String formatting.

```
public class Division {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int dividend = scan.nextInt();
        int divider = scan.nextInt();
        divisionEngine(dividend, divider);
        scan.close();
    }

    public static List<Integer> getDigits(int dividend) {
        List<Integer> digitArray = new ArrayList<>();

        while (dividend > 0) {
            digitArray.add(dividend % 10);
            dividend = dividend / 10;
        }
        Collections.reverse(digitArray);
        return digitArray;
    }

    public static int divisionEngine(int dividend, int divider) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int dividerLength = String.valueOf(divider).length();
        int result = 0;
        int substraction = 0;
        int variable = Integer.parseInt(getDigits(dividend).subList(0, dividerLength).toString().replace("[", "")
                .replace("]", "").replace(", ", ""));

        while (dividerLength != getDigits(dividend).size()) {
            result = Math.abs(variable / divider);
            builder.append(result);
            substraction = Math.abs(result * divider);
            variable = Integer.parseInt(Math.abs(variable - substraction) + "".concat(getDigits(dividend)
                    .get(dividerLength++).toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(", ", "")));

            if (variable < divider) {

                while (variable < substraction && dividerLength != getDigits(dividend).size()) {
                    variable = Integer.parseInt(variable + "".concat(getDigits(dividend).get(dividerLength++).toString()
                            .replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(", ", "")));
                    builder.append(0);
                }
            }
            if (substraction != 0) {
                System.out.println(substraction + "\n" + variable);
            }

        }

        if (dividerLength == getDigits(dividend).size()) {
            result = Math.abs(variable / divider);
            substraction = Math.abs(result * divider);
            variable -= Math.abs(substraction);
            builder.append(result);
            result = Integer.parseInt(builder.toString());

            if (substraction > variable) {
                System.out.println(substraction + "\n" + variable);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("= " + result);

        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (dividerLength != getDigits(dividend).size()) {
    result = Math.abs(variable / divider);
    builder.append(result);
    substraction = Math.abs(result * divider);
    variable = Integer.parseInt(variable - substraction + "".concat(getDigits(dividend).get(dividerLength++)
            .toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(", ", "")));

    if (variable < divider && variable < initVariable) {
        variable = Integer.parseInt(variable + "".concat(getDigits(dividend).get(dividerLength++)
                .toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(", ", "")));
        builder.append(0);
    }
```

within the above section of code, you running the while-loop, while the `dividerLength` is smaller than the length of the dividend.

But WITHIN that loop, you use `dividerLength++` 2 times, which will lead to a dividerLength greater than what is allowed. Only increment once per loop, to make sure it stays within the array bounds.

Second:
When the count is "5", you have indexes 0-4 to access. - so use `dividerLength -1` to access the index - or make sure that it is incremented at the end, so the "6th run" (with dividerLength=5) won't happen.

```
while (dividerLength != getDigits(dividend).size()) {
    result = Math.abs(variable / divider);
    builder.append(result);
    substraction = Math.abs(result * divider);
    variable = Integer.parseInt(variable - substraction + "".concat(getDigits(dividend).get(dividerLength)
            .toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(", ", "")));

    if (variable < divider && variable < initVariable) {
        variable = Integer.parseInt(variable + "".concat(getDigits(dividend).get(dividerLength)
                .toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(", ", "")));
        builder.append(0);

    dividerLength += 1;
    }
```